# Drag and drop editing

Tags: front-end

Recently I updated to version 10, and now drag and drop editing in the front end doesn't work. In the Options Inspector->Editing Options->Private Editing Options, the DragAndDrop item is grayed out, and I can't check the box.

Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: DrapAndDrop seems to be strictly a Global option, so in the OptionsInspector be sure you've selected Global rather than Selected Notebook or Selected.

Comment: In version 10.2 on Windows I can check the box but there is still no drag & drop.

Comment: @murray is right. You have to select "Global" as your scope. Mine works fine. Version 10.2 on Windows.

Comment: @murray: Hmm. I did have Selected, rather than Global. Hence the gray. So, I hit Global, and DragAndDrop is checked as True. But still, it isn't working in any notebooks.

Comment: The old `DragAndDrop` FE option is being obsoleted. I would not expect it to work in any recent _Mathematica_ version.